# g++ strstr says invalid conversion from const char * to char *

Tags: c++, string

I am converting a project written in C++ for windows.  Everything is going fine (meaning I clearly see what needs to be changed to make things proper C++) until I hit this, which is my own little routine to find a keyword in along string of keyword=value pairs:

```
bool GetParameter(const char * haystack, const char *needle) {
    char *search, *start;
    int len;
    len = strlen(needle) + 4;     //  make my own copy so I can upper case it...
    search = (char *) calloc(1,len);
    if (search == NULL) return false;
    strcpy(search,needle);
    strupr(search);
    strcat(search,"=");           //  now it is 'KEYWORD='
    start = strstr(haystack,search);  <---- ERROR from compiler
```

g++ is telling me "Invalid conversion from const char * to char *  "
(the precise location of the complaint is the argument variable 'search' )

But it would appear that g++ is dyslexic.  Because I am actually going the **other way**. I am passing in a char * to a const char *

(so the conversion is "from char * to const char *" )

The strstr prototype is char * strstr(const char **, const char **)

There is no danger here.  Nothing in any const char * is being modified.
Why is it telling me this?
What can I do to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are two overloads of `strstr` - the one that takes two `const char*` parameters also returns `const char*`.

Comment: You're converting a project to C++ or is it the other way around?

Comment: I wasn't aware there are two prototypes.   Where is the other one (so I can remove it)?   As far as I know I am using <string.h>

Comment: I am going C++  Visual C++ 6.0 from MS to g++.  Both are  cpp files.

Comment: You can't remove standard library functions, nor should you.

Comment: Why would you want to modify the standard library?

Comment: The diagnostice clearly says:
tools.cpp: 184:32: error: invalid conversion from const char * to chart *
So, it is not the return value.

Or are you claiming that there are two functions of signature that only differ by their return (char * vs const char *) ?

Comment: @user2832155 The two functions differ in their return type *and* their parameter types

Comment: When I asked how to remove it, I was attempting to figure out which different header is may be in, so I can avoid it, and use the declaration I want.  Not remove the library function, just avoid the declaration.  It's all understood now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is not regarding the arguments to `stsrtr`. Compiler is complaining about the conversion of the '`const char *`' returned by `strstr`. You can't assign it to `*start` which is just `char *`

You can try one of these:

```
const char *start;
```

or

```
string start(strstr(haystack,search));
```

Comment: However the compiler told me the error was at 184:32.  And column 32 is not the end of the function arguments, nor the assignment.  It is specifically on the second argument.  I'd call that a bad diagnostic.  It should tell me the right location, or none at all.  Not the wrong one.  The MS Visual Studio (for all it's other sloppiness) at least says it's an assignment error.

Comment: Yes, GCC's location diagnostics are no good at pointing to the right part within an expression, but with my version of GCC it's pointing to the closing parenthesis, not the second argument

Comment: Hmmm...  "search); "  plus eight characters is the closing semicolon.  I think it may be correct.  My editor is setting the tabs to 8.  Gotta laugh at that one.  And learn something.

Answer (score 9):

The background to the problem is that C defines the function `strstr` as:

```
char* strstr(const char*, const char*);
```

This is because C doesn't allow overloaded functions, so to allow you to use `strstr` with both const and non-const strings it accepts const strings and returns non-const.  This introduces a weakness in C's already fragile type-system, because it removes const-ness from a string. It is the C programmer's job to not attempt to write via a pointer returned from `strstr` if you pased in non-modifiable strings.

In C++ the function is replaced by a pair of overloaded functions, the standard says:

> 7. The function signature `strstr(const char*, const char*)` shall be replaced by the two declarations:
>       `const char* strstr(const char* s1, const char* s2);`
>       `char* strstr( char* s1, const char* s2);`
>   both of which shall have the same behavior as the original declaration.

This is type-safe, if you pass in a const string you get back a const string.  Your code passes in a const string, so G++ is following the standard by returning a const string. You get what you asked for.

Your code compiles on Windows because apparently the standard library you were using on Windows doesn't provide the overloads and only provides the C version.  That allows you to pass in const strings and get back a non-const string. G++ provides the C++ versions, as required by the standard.  The error is telling you that you're trying to convert the const return value to a non-const `char*`. The solution is the assign the return value to a `const char*` instead, which is portable and compiles everywhere.

Comment: *like*   Yeah, maintaining it on an old compiler on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Although declaring `start` as `const char*` might suffice, what seems more appropriate to me is to use `std::string` objects instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

bool GetParameter(const char * haystack, const char *needle) {

    std::string hstr(haystack), nstr(needle);
    std::transform(nstr.begin(), nstr.end(),nstr.begin(), ::toupper);
    nstr += "=";

    std::size_t found = hstr.find(nstr);
    if (found != std::string::npos) {
        ...                                 // "NEEDLE=" found
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have a +1, you need `#include <ctype.h>` for `::toupper` though

Comment: Thanks, but for me 'you go with what you know', and I didn't want to take on a bigger rewrite using std::strings because I have to slice out the value it finds. It's just getting the code to cross compile right now that is my goal.

Coming from assembler and pure "C", I'll migrate to string when I have more time to trip over my mistakes.

Comment: @user2832155: You can not do anything wrong by using standard library. Additionally, it will be guaranteed by the standard that this behavior will be the same regardless the environment or compiler.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I think `<cctype>` is already included by `<algorithm>`

Comment: @LihO: The synopsis for `<algorithm>` (at 25.1/2) only shows that `<algorithm>` is required to include `<initializer_list>`. Implementations are free to include whatever else they'd like, of course, but you aren't guaranteed to get the other headers across implementations. You have to include `<cctype>` explicitly in this case, to be portable.

Comment: @GManNickG: Fair enough :)

Comment: @GManNickG,  `<ctype.h>` not `<cctype>`. The latter is only guaranteed to declare `std::toupper` but that is overloaded in `<locale>`, so to avoid the ambiguity it's simplest to use `::toupper` and that means including `<ctype.h>`. Otherwise, spot on.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Good call.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion it is complaining about is from `strstr(...)` to `start`. Change the declaration of `start` to `const char* start;`

Comment: "man strstr"  told me that the return is char *.  Not const.
I guess I was steered wrong by the man page.
Plus by the diagnostic telling me that the error was at column 32.

Comment: Worked. Thanks.  But scary.   What if I wanted to modify the original char array based on what was located (say replace a word with spaces to redact some text)?  Now I have to "roll my own" method to do a sub string search.  I could have done it in regular C.

Comment: @user2832155 But you declared your original char array as const `const char * haystack`, if you hadn't done that you wouldn't have faced this problem. All the two overloads of strstr do is *preserve* the constness of your declarations.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of those C vs C++ things I suppose.  const char * always meant to me that the function was gonna hold the array constant (not mess with it's contents).   So the way I looked at it, both overloads should be declared 'const' because they are not changing the array contents.

The "what are you doing with this data" versus "what was I doing with this data".

Comment: @user2832155, `haystack` is const, how would you modify it, without risking undefined behaviour?

Comment: Mixed examples.  Probably not the best way to describe it.  Anyway, this was because "man strstr" steered me to C, rather than the C++ signatures.  Where (if at all) can the man pages for C++ be found?

Comment: `strstr` taking a `const char*` does mean it won't alter the string, but why should it also mean it changes the type?  The C version of `strstr` only does that because C doesn't support overloading, not because it's a good idea.  Try http://cppreference.com for C++ references, GCC's C++ libary doesn't generally install man pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can use such like:

```
start = const_cast<char *>(strstr( haystack, static_cast<const char *>(search) ));
```